# Is there a way to find out what type of disk is being used in a virtual machine in Azure using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to find out what type of disk is using a VM in Azure, specifically I need to know if the disk is SSD or HDD, using powershell.

I  know I can find that info in the Azure portal, but I need to do so using a powershell script.

With the StorageProfile property of a Virtual machine object, I can find some info:

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $azureVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk

    OsType                  : Windows
    EncryptionSettings      :
    Name                    : ServerX1Disk0
    Vhd                     :
    Image                   :
    Caching                 : ReadWrite
    WriteAcceleratorEnabled :
    DiffDiskSettings        :
    CreateOption            : Attach
    DiskSizeGB              : 256
    ManagedDisk             : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ManagedDiskParameters
```

But I cannot find the info about if this disk is SSD or HDD.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to judge the disk type, SSD or HDD.

The first is that like the other answer describes, the `StorageAccountType` not only decide the disk redundancy, also decide the disk type. There are 4 values, but only the `Standard_LRS` means the HDD type and other mean SSD.

The second way is that use the PowerShell command to get the information of the disk itself like this:

```
$disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName groupName -Name diskName
```

And the `$disk.Sku` also shows the disk type. The Sku name has 4 values: Standard_LRS, Premium_LRS, StandardSSD_LRS, UltraSSD_LRS. Only the value Standard_LRS means the HDD type, others mean SSD. You can see the description in the [Azure Disk Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2018-09-30/disks#disksku-object).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've tested the values for the StorageAccountType while changing the configuration of the disk and matches your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The following property is what you are looking for:

```
$azureVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.StorageAccountType
```

If you have data disks, they are accessed on a different property (`DataDisks`). Keep in mind that `DataDisks` property is a collection so you may need to use indexing or loop to access the disk(s) you want:

```
$azureVM.StorageProfile.DataDisks[index].ManagedDisk.StorageAccountType
```

> Possible values for StorageAccountType include: 'Standard_LRS', 'Premium_LRS',
>   'StandardSSD_LRS', 'UltraSSD_LRS'. NOTE: UltraSSD_LRS can only be used
>   with data disks, it cannot be used with OS Disk.

See [Azure Managed Disk Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-types#standard-ssd) for details on the disk types.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Now I understand that 'Standard_HDD' disks will show 'Standard_LRS' in the StorageAccountType property,  'Standard SSD' will  show 'StandardSSD_LRS', and a Premium SSD disk will show 'Premium_LRS' in that property.